# Adding columns to a DataTable using SetOrdinal

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a DataTable with five columns. I am curious as to why the following works:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Blah").SetOrdinal(5);
```

But the following throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Blah").SetOrdinal(dt.Columns.Count);
```

I also tried

```
dt.Columns.Add("Blah").SetOrdinal(dt.Columns.Count - 1);
```

which works, but I'm not entirely sure why. Does it have something to do with the column being added before the `SetOrdinal` is executed, thus increasing the count beyond the range of columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Does it have something to do with the column being added before the SetOrdinal is executed"

Yes.

At the time the last part is evaluated:

```
.SetOrdinal(dt.Columns.Count);
```

dt.Columns.Count == 6. Generally speaking you should avoid compound statements that reference something that changes in the same statement. Although the evaluation order is predictable it's not especially intuitive -- you'll end up making mistakes. This is better:

```
var count = dt.Columns.Count;
dt.Columns.Add("Blah").SetOrdinal(count);
```

or even better:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Blah");
dt.Columns.SetOrdinal(dt.Columns.Count-1);
```

Don't try to make your code shorter just for the sake of making it shorter. If saving a few characters (which really means nothing in compiled code) makes the intent less clear, then it's definitely not worth it.

Comment: Well explained, thank you. Good advice on avoiding code that is less clear.

Comment: This is a little old, but I think you meant this instead:  
  
    dt.Columns.Add("Blah");  
    dt.Columns["Blah"].SetOrdinal(dt.Columns.Count-1);  

But really this is a NOP since the new column will be added to the end anyway.  This would be a more interesting example, which moves the new column to the beginning:  
  
    dt.Columns.Add("Blah");  
    dt.Columns["Blah"].SetOrdinal(0);

Comment: I tried to get better formatting, but I guess I can't.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinal is zero-based, you need to take this into consideration when using `Count`.

Example:

```
dt.Columns.Count = 5;

//1. dt.Columns[0]
//2. dt.Columns[1]
//3. dt.Columns[2]
//4. dt.Columns[3]
//5. dt.Columns[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

DataColumn will start from "0" 
The better way you 1st add a column into data table and use SetOrdinal

```
DataColumn newcol=new DataColumn("Blah", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add(newcol);
newcol.SetOrdinal(dt.Columns.Count-1);
```